# Openldap Cannot load private key/certificate pair from Windows store

Tags: ssl, certificate, openldap, private-key

I have an OpenLdap server on my system configured to use certificates from the Windows Store for TLS.

In my slapd.conf file I have TLSCertificateFile and TLSCACertificateFile parameters set to the subject of my certificate. (The subject name is correct for sure, because I use the same config on another computer and it works)

The problem is that I have the certificates in the Windows Store and I have the private key but the OpenLdap is giving me the following error:

```
Info   :0:CA certificate 'CN=RootCA' loaded from Windows store
Info   :0:Certificate 'CN=child' loaded from Windows store 'MY'
ERROR  :-2509:Load device private key 'CN=child' from windows store 'MY' failed
ERROR  :-2509:Cannot load private key/certificate pair from Windows store
TLS: could not use certificate `CN=child'.
TLS: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch .\crypto\x509\x509_cmp.c:318
TLS: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory .\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:398
TLS: error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib .\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:400
TLS: error:140AD002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file:system lib .\ssl\ssl_rsa.c:470
52ef8879 main: TLS init def ctx failed: -1
```

So when I open the mmc/Certificates view I can see the certificates in appropriate places and they have private keys but obviously OpenLdap cannot find them for some reason.

Did anyone have the similar issue?